# Stop VBA code running when incorrect password is entered

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large VBA macro running that I did not build. It unprotects sheets to do work on them and then re-protects them, always with the same password. Eventually this code will output the error box below indicating the incorrect password was entered. The VBA editor is frozen at this point because the message box is up. How do I stop the macro from running so I can check what line in the code is causing the problem?

[Excel Incorrect Password MsgBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ8Mh.png)

Pressing ok on the text box results in the code continuing and a different error occurring later. I tried Esc-Esc and Ctrl-Break to stop the code from running but I don't think I'm using them correctly

Comment: Have you tried to press Ctrl+Break when this message pops up?

Comment: I have tried ctrl-pause and fn-B, ctrl-fn-B as I do not have a break key. As I understand the Pause key is also the break key. Excel doesn't seem affected it continues to hang

Comment: If Ctrl+Break isn't working can you get into the code (Alt+F11) when  you first open the workbook?  If so find the `MsgBox` that displays the error and put a breakpoint on it.

Comment: That was helpful thank you, I was able to use that method to isolate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply attribute your MsgBox to a variable, and do an If clause to Exit Sub. The code below works even if the user clicks the X button.

```
result = MsgBox("You have entered an incorrect password. All worksheets could not be unprotected", vbCritical, "Incorrect Password")

If result = vbOK Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```